# Understanding debugDiag report

Tags: c#, iis, windbg, debugdiag, debug-diagnostic-tool

We are facing an issue with IIS. Our .net 4.5 Web API application hosted on IIS 8.5 stop serving response. if we look at the worker process, request are queued up. Any subsequent request to same url is blocked by IIS.

[image]

The memory and CPU usage on the server is under control. Event viewer does not have any error. To investigate the issue, we took the memory dump during the issue and ran it through DebugDiag tool.

The report is indicating some sort of deadlock.

```
Detected a serious critical section related problem in w3wp.exe_190920_105811.dmp

Lock at 0x0ef4fcc0 owned by thread 22 is Deadlocked with lock at 0x0ef66ee0 owned by thread 26

Impact analysis

1 critical sections indirectly blocked

Critical Sections 0x0ef4fbe0)

32.69% of threads blocked

(Threads 25 26 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42)

The following functions are involved in the root cause

clr!CrstBase::SpinEnter+92

The following modules are involved in the root cause

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll from Microsoft Corporation
```

I am not sure how can I investigate this issue. I have no clue about DebugDiag tool. Please suggest.

Comment: The same report should show you what is thread 26 and how its call stack looks like. You need to analyze that and also review the relevant code in your project. If you lack of that experience, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: @LexLi: I looked the section below and could not understand a think. I tried using windbg and had no luck.  I am unable to load SOS file as I am using win32 application and SOS files from server is 64 bit.

Comment: Like I said, I don't expect you (or anyone else) to learn the stuffs yourself. You need professional support, not luck.